# Flink Table API shuffling column values for one particular topic

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink job (written in Scala) which is enriching a stream with other streams. The streams are coming from Kafka topics. I read the topics with a schema using the table API and then convert them to datastreams.

For only one of the topics, the column values are shuffled when I log the schema/columns immediately after converting to datastream (i.e. column 1 will always contain the value of column 4), and I have no clue why it's the case. The schema is read correctly (logging the schema/column names gives me expected results).

Things I've checked:

- The schema is read correctly
- The columns are not in alphabetical order
- The Kafka topic's messages are as I would expect them to be
- I use the exact same code to read other Kafka topics and they work just fine
- I've updated to the latest version of Flink

For now my only workarounds are either to manually reshuffle the columns in a select statement or to read just this stream using the datastream api directly.

Edit:

I am using Avro schemas, Kafka topic format is avro-confluent. I build the table descriptor as so:

```
    val schemaString   = Source.fromResource(schemaPath).mkString
    val schemaDataType = AvroSchemaConverter.convertToDataType(schemaString)
    val schema         = Schema.newBuilder().fromRowDataType(schemaDataType).build()

    val tableDescriptor = TableDescriptor
      .forConnector("kafka")
      .schema(schema)
      .comment(topicName)
      .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.TOPIC, List(topicName).asJava)
      .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.VALUE_FORMAT, "avro-confluent")
      .option("value.avro-confluent.url", config.getString("schema.registry.url"))
      .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.PROPS_GROUP_ID, mainOutputTopicName)
      .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.PROPS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, bootstrapServers)
      .build()
```

I get a table from it and convert it to a stream:

```
val table = tableEnv.from(tableDescriptor)

val stream = tableEnv.toDataStream(table, classOf[DataType])
```

Comment: Which data format you reading in Kafka and your code could gave more information probably.

Comment: I edited to include this

Comment: And if you add `.format()` to your TableDescriptor ? And you probably need to create a table with your tableDescriptor first, and read from table. like in example [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/common/#connector-tables)